# How to build Neural Network in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neural-network, word2vec

The flow should be:

Input -> Word2Vectors -> Output -> NeuralNetwork

I have tried word2vec function of spark but I am confused with the format "MultilayerPerceptronClassifier" need as a input?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the problem related to the input dimension of your MultilayerPerceptrionClassifier (which is a sub-case of a NN that should NOT be used) or regarding to Word2Vec? If you train a Word2Vec model yourself on some text corpus you can set the output dimensions as a parameter. The output dimension of the word2vec model should match the input dimension of the MultilayerPerceptionClassifier (which you should not use, rather look for http://deeplearning4j.org/).

Comment: I am confused with the dimension of MultilayerPerceptronNetwork. what is should be? so that accordingly i can set same dimensions of my word2vec model

Comment: The first layer of the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier should have input dimension = output of Word2Vec (usually called feature dimension).

Comment: Yes that i came to know. But what are the dimensions? Can you give example?

Comment: `val layers = Array[Int](featureSize, 5, 4, 3)`, where featureSize is set to the length of the word2vec vectors. The `Word2VecModel` has a `vectorSize` attribute, that is the one you need to use for `featureSize`, but unfortunately it is set to `private`. However, you can look it up once and insert the length of the vectors that are given as output of your Word2VecModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your `MultilayerPerceptronClassifier` you have to give as parameter an `Array[Int]` called `layers`. These describe the number of neurons per layer in that sequence. The first layer's input dimension must match the length of the `Word2Vec` output dimension. So you should set the parameter to

```
val layers = Array[Int](featureDim, 5, 4, 5, ...)
```

And replace the numbers with the parameters you want your model to have. You should set `featureDim` to the length of the vectors your `Word2VecModel` produces. Unfortunately, the attribute with that value is hidden via a `private` accessor and there is no getter method implemented as of now.